# Segfault when capturing this in template class

Tags: c++11, gcc

While learning C++11 features I've noticed that this code crashes with segfault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <int X = 42>
struct Test {
    int x = X;
    void printer() {
        cout << "this value: " << x <<  endl;
    }
    std::function<void()> lambda = [this] {printer();};
};


int main()
{
    Test<> t;
    t.lambda();
    return 0;
}
```

If I make Test a regular struct instead of template it works. Why is that?
Os: Ubuntu 16.04, compiler : g++ 6.3

Edit: Works on Clang. Must be a G++ bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the experiment, it works with g++8.1, and crashes with segfault on g++7.3. Through gdb trace, it is found that when the error occurs, the `this` pointer captured by the lambda is null, which is related to the strategy of the compiler to initialize the lambda variable(`this` pointer is not initialized yet when compiler initializes lambda). It can work by putting the initialization in the initialization list of the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <int X = 42>
struct Test {
    int x = X;
    void printer() {
        cout << "this value: " << x <<  endl;
    }
    std::function<void()> lambda;
    Test():lambda([this] {printer();}){}
};


int main()
{
    Test<> t;
    t.lambda();
    return 0;
}
```